# Is bareword filehandle package variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

The legacy bareword filehandle looks in global scope, is it parsed as package variable? Why isn't it prepended with punctuation sign (`$`)?

```
open FILE, 'file.txt';
```

Comment: It is and old way to open a file. Use instead `open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!`

Comment: Don't think in scopes. It's in the symbol table (perl has two non-compatible ways of storing variables).

Answer (score 5):

If you look at `perldoc -f ref` you will see that there are more data types than there are identifying sigils. The only defined ones are

- `$` - **SCALAR**
- `@` - **ARRAY**
- `%` - **HASH**
- `&` - **CODE**

the rest are identified by context.

If you write

```
package Pack;

open FH, '<', 'file';
```

then `FH` appears in the `Pack` symbol table as the **IO** variable `Pack::FH`. It isn't preceded by a dollar `$` because it is an **IO** variable, not a **SCALAR**. Without a preceding `package` statement, it will be placed in the default `main` namespace. So with your example

```
open FILE, 'file.txt'
```

you can then read from the `FILE` handle using the fully-qualified `main::FILE` like this

```
while (<main::FILE>) {
  :
  :
}
```

Comment: What's the condition for bareword to be parsed as IO variable? Just as the first parameter for open, close and inside <> operator?

Comment: @Thomson: I can't help you there: you are asking about the innermost working of the Perl compiler. I could probably find out from the C source given time, but do you really need to know, or are you just asking out of interest? After all, global file handles are now considered bad practice, and you shouldn't be writing new code that uses them.

Comment: Just for understanding this better. It will be great if you could point me to the source, but not hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Used to be a convention in Perl - filehandles were all uppercase, and globally scoped.

This started with `STDIN` (and the other standard file streams) and so you could do:

```
while ( <STDIN> ) {
    print;
}
```

Perl's open command supports a 'legacy' mode of opening, which is:

```
open ( FILEHANDLE, ">filename.txt" );
```

It's not recommended to use this any more, but it can't be removed without breaking legacy code.

Instead you should:

```
 open ( my $filehandle, ">", 'filename.txt' ) or die $!;
 print {$filehandle} "Some Text\n";
```

This has two advantages:

- your filehandle is lexically scoped, so you don't have to worry about a module writing to 'OUTPUT' or similar.
- Because it's lexically scoped, it automatically closes when it goes out of scope.
- 3 argument open avoids injection exploits.

Comment: That's useful and looks correct, but it doesn't seem to answer the question.